# Soundcloud player z-order (wmode) is wrong: Bad Flash! Bad?

Tags: bug, status-completed, audio

Links to audio files hosted on SoundCloud [automagically turn into a player](https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58/embedded-audio-player/176#176).  This is great!  However, I tried to upvote the implementation post, which is currently beneath earlier, higher-voted posts.  I wasn't logged in, so it sent the "Please log in" popup.  This appeared below the player:

[image]

The player should go behind almost anything that appears on the page, including this message.  Unfortunately, this in't how Flash wants to work.

You currently add the player with this embed:

```
<object height="81" width="100%">
            <param name="movie" value="http://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F18311992&amp;auto_play=false">
            <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
            <embed src="http://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F18311992&amp;auto_play=false" allowscriptaccess="always" height="81" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%">     
</object>
```

I realize that you probably copied this code from http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/widget#quick-start, (By the way - ***thank you*** for disabling auto-play), but this leaves the Flash in its default

```
<param name="wmode" value="let_my_ads_bleed_through_everything">
```

state.  This can be fixed from your side, SO can [help](https://stackoverflow.com/q/326196/325514) [you](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1515939/325514) [with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050999/youtube-iframe-wmode-issue) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wmode).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already did all the work, there's not much left to say :)

From the next build on, the `wmode` parameter is set to `opaque`. Note that this happens at post render time, so this isn't fixed retroactively, but only on edit (I consider that okay, since it's not a really major issue).

Thanks!